# Is it possible in an Angular project with Bootstrap using the Angular Material for Drag and Drop?

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, angular-material

In my angular project, I'm using Bootstrap for responsive Design. 
On one site, data should be sorted via Drag and Drop. Are there any other nice possibilities than the Drag-and-Drop-Module by Angular Material (https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/overview)? 
If not, is it possibile to use both Material and Bootstrap by just using the Drag-and-Drop-Module of Material and the other Styling of Bootstrap?

Comment: `@angular/cdk` does not depend on any Angular Material styling. You can use the modules/patterns from `@angular/cdk` effectively in any Angular application without affecting styles. What have you tried so far?

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky I've tried using the `@angular/cdk` - it works fine!

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, decided not to go with the Angular Material

Easy and Simple - https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-drag-drop

A little more complex but with good features - https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-dragula

And you can keep the bootstrap layout.

Comment: Thanks! Great packages